# JAVA : time factor regarding Array Dimension

Tags: java, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

i have a coding experience in **C++**.
Recently, i've been trying to learn Java.

I was practicing a simple problem at an Online Judge.
the problem required an array of 2x1000000 dimension.
i declared an array:

`int ara[][]=new int[1000000][2]`

but the code could not fit within 3 second time limit and got Time Limit Exceeded verdict in the very first test case.

then i just switched the dimension like this :

`int ara[][]=new int[2][1000000]`

and altered the code accordingly and the code got accepted.

after some experiment i figured that was the only reason my first code got Time Limit Exceeded.

What is the difference between `int ara[][]=new int[1000000][2]` and `int ara[][]=new int[2][1000000]` ?
Why is there such a huge significant time difference between those array declaration ?

Comment: What do you think is faster? Allocating 1000000 arrays with 2 values each or allocating 2 arrays with 1000000 values each? Why do you think so?

Comment: Coming from C++, you probably think that `int[3][5]` is a 2-dimensional array. It is not. It is an array of arrays. Big difference internally, though functionally it can *behave* like a 2D array. But being an array of arrays, each secondary array can actually be a different size, which a pure 2D array can't do. See [JLS 15.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2) and look at example 15.10.2-2 to see what's going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory takes time. Allocating one array of 5 elements does not take the same amount of time as allocating 5 arrays of one element. For each allocation, the OS has to look in the page table for a free block, assign it, etc.

So in one example you declare only 2 arrays, in the other you declare 1000000. That is why one is faster than the other.